# Filter files by date range in OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I would like to obtain the OneDrive content using Microsoft Graph filtered by date so that only files created between particular dates are obtained.

I have tried:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/children?filter=createdDateTime ge 2016-02-26T14:41:09Z
```

but get following response

```json
"error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "c636022f-2fa9-4e41-b8fc-63be5fc5e681",
        "date": "2017-04-07T10:05:46"
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?filter=name eq 'folderapr05'
```

and it works.

Does OneDrive support filter parameter for dates?

Answer (score 3):

Filtering by `dateTime` isn't supported.

If you're attempting to do this for the purposes of syncing with OneDrive, you may want to take a look at [delta](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/item_delta). This method allows your app to track changes to a drive and its children over time.

Comment: That is incorrect, [`/delta`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_delta) is _not_ a beta API. It was released to GA about a month after this answer was written.